# ArcGIS 10.1 and Python add-ins

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, arcgis

I recently installed ArcGIS 10.1 on a 64-bit machine. It runs just fine and installed Python 2.7 automatically just fine as well. I am now trying to install a 64-bit version of matplotlib and get the following error: Python 2.7 not found in registry. It is however in the registry under the wow6432 node. Installing 64-bit Python 2.7 fixes this issue, but then the integration with ArcGIS is not there anymore. Has anyone encountered this issue and knows how to solve it? Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Kat

Comment: Does ArcGIS 10.1 only work with 32bit python? If that's the case then you should probably use 32bit matplotlib. Also python module versions should match the installed python version (i.e. 32bit module go with 32bit python, regardless of weather the machine is 32 or 64 bit).

Comment: I feel really silly now. I just assumed I have 64-bit python, when indeed it is 32bit. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unrelated error